# How to find in SOLR copyright symbol (©)

Tags: apache, pdf, solr, apache-tika

I have 20 ml documents in Solr (v 6.3). I indexed it from pdf files (used Apache Tika)
I need find all documents with copyright symbol (©) in content.
But, Solr remove this symbol from query string:
Query:[image: query with copyright symbol with none result]

But solr has indexed file with copyright symbol: 
[image: document in solr with copyright symbol]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Raw Query Parser

> RawQParser extends the QParserPlugin by creating a term query from the
>   input value without any text analysis or transformation. This is
>   useful in debugging, or when raw terms are returned from the terms
>   component (this is not the default). The only parameter is f, which
>   defines the field to search.

Example:

```
 {!raw f=myfield}©
```

It will return all the results containing Copyright symbol.

Comment: Thanks! But I anyway can not get docs with copyright  `{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "q": "{!raw f=_content_}©",
      "debug": "query",
      "fl": "id",
      "start": "0",
      "rows": "1",
      "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  },
  "debug": {
    "rawquerystring": "{!raw f=_content_}©",
    "querystring": "{!raw f=_content_}©",
    "parsedquery": "_content_:©",
    "parsedquery_toString": "_content_:©",
    "QParser": ""
  }
}`

Comment: `curl "http://localhost:8985/solr/lib-forms/query?wt=json&fl=id&start=0&debug=query&q=%7B!raw%20f%3D_content_%7D%C2%A9&rows=1"`  Maybe problem with client url_encode()? I use mac os post client

Comment: @DenisOgr As you can see that by changing the parser, we can search the special character. But it can't solve the problem if there is a mismatch between search string and content.

Comment: @DenisOgr Share the **Schema** that you are using for content. May be the Analyzers removing the copyright from the index. That's why it is not coming in search result.

Comment: This is [filed with content](http://pastebin.com/anm2ZHVd) and [fieldtypes schema](http://pastebin.com/ifjNnLuR). What part of schema show more?

Comment: @DenisOgr **Word Delimiter Filter** filter removing the copyright symbol from index. That's why it is not coming in search result. You can create new **Copy Field** in which you can discard the above Filter in order to find copyright symbol.

Comment: I added new **Copy Field**, but I don`t see content in this new field and does not work search by this field. Do I need re-index document?   PS: I send message in  chat with you.

Comment: Yes you need to re-index the document in order to add new field.

Comment: Thx, very much!